# Segmentation fault with OpenALPR

Tags: c++, ocr, openalpr

I'm trying to install OpenALPR on Laravel Homestead (Ubuntu 18.04). First I tried [The Easiest Way](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Ubuntu-Linux)#the-easiest-way). I'm trying to run:

> ```
> Error opening data file /usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/lus.traineddata
> Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
> Failed loading language 'lus'
> Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

I `cd` into `/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr` directory, and I did not find the `lus.traineddata` file. But there was an *ocr* folder and there was a `lus.traineddata`. I copied it from there to the directory up, tried again to recognize but this time:

> --(!) Runtime directory '/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data' is invalid. Missing OCR data for the country: 'us'!
>   Error loading OpenALPR

Then I tried [The Easy Way](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Ubuntu-Linux)#the-easy-way). Everything was compiled normally. But:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 7):

This happens because openALPR's Tesseract OCR expects its trained data in a specific path and the files are not there. 
According to the error message it can be set using the `TESSDATA_PREFIX`environment variable but in my own experience didn't work.

I came accross with nother solution; it's not the best way but it may work.

I created a symbolic link from `/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/tessdata/lus.traineddata` to `/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/lus.traineddata` in order to make the trainedData files available to tesseract/openalpr right where they expect them.

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/tessdata/lus.traineddata /usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/lus.traineddata`

repeat the command changing `lus` with the desired language/region  file (leu, lfr, ...)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is because the language trained data is in `[runtime_data path]/ocr/tessdata/` in tesseract 4.0 unlike tesseract 3.0 which stores them in `[runtime_data path]/ocr/`.

This problem is fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/commit/28e0b0fa95c12923138768d670b852242a750d0c).

But it seems that the version of openalpr in the apt-get repository is behind this commit.

So the temporary solution is moving language data to `[runtime_data path]/ocr` like danielillu’s solution.

Since ‘us’ country config only require lus.traineddata file, you only need to move lus.traineddata file.